# nodemon : clean exit waiting for changes before restart

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jestjs, nodemon

Hello I do not understand I can not play server anymore.

.env PORT=4000

server.listen is exported in start.ts for the tests to work without saying "PORT is already busy"

My project is typescript, express, jest api.

When I "npm run dev" I got no connection on localhost:4000:

```
spark-administration-bff|automaticSwagger⚡ ⇒ npm run dev

> spark_backend@1.0.0 dev /Users/julie/Documents/groupe_rocher/spark-administration/spark-administration-bff
> nodemon

[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): src/**/*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts
[nodemon] starting `npm start`

> spark_backend@1.0.0 start /Users/julie/Documents/groupe_rocher/spark-administration/spark-administration-bff
> node dist/src/index.js

[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
_____________________________
```

When I "npm test" :
I got first "[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart" then if I "ctrl C":

the tests are all running green PASS, with just 2 warnings:

(node:4549) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
(node:4549) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block,...

#project tree

```
/dist
|__src
   |__index.js
   |__start.js
/src
|__modules
|__routes
|__index.ts
|__start.ts
/tests
```

#Package.json

```
{
  "name": "spark_backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuilt": "tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json --fix",
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "concurrently --kill-others npm:watch-*",
    "watch typescript": "tsc -w",
    "watch-node": "nodemon dist/index.js",
    "pretest": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test npm run dev",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --verbose --watchAll --forceExit --maxWorkers=1",
    "start": "node .",
    "start-dev": "nodemon index.ts",
    "dev": "nodemon"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-formidable": "^1.2.0",
    "git-flow": "^0.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^4.0.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.4",
    "ts-jest": "^26.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^9.1.1",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.7",
    "@types/express-formidable": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.5",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.23",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/swagger-jsdoc": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.2",
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "tslint": "^6.1.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/nodes_modules"
    ]
  }
}
```

#start.ts

```
const server = require("./index");

server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
  console.log("encore sylvie started");
});
```

#index.ts

```
require("dotenv").config();
import express from "express";
const formidableMiddleware = require("express-formidable");
import cors from "cors";
import swaggerUi from "swagger-ui-express";
import * as SwaggerDocument from "./swagger.json";

const server: express.Application = express();
server.use(formidableMiddleware());
server.use(cors());

// swagger
server.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(SwaggerDocument));

// ROUTES 

const usersRoute = require("./routes/Users");
server.use(usersRoute);

const customersRoute = require("./routes/Customers");
server.use(customersRoute);

// OTHERS

server.get("/", (req: any, res: any) => {
  res.send("Welcome to Spark Admin back end!");
});

server.all("*", (req: any, res: any) => {
  res.status(404).json({ error: "Web url not found" });
});

module.exports = server;
```

#example of test:

```
import express from "express";
const server = require("../../src/index");
const request = require("supertest")(server);

describe("user connexion giving token", function () {
  it('should respond with 400 : miss "client_credentials" as grant_type', async function (done) {
    request
      .post("/users/oauth")
      .expect(400)
      .end(function (err: any) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

#tsconfig just in case:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src", "tests"],
  "types": ["jest", "node"]
}
```

Comment: [nodemon] starting `npm start`

> spark_backend@1.0.0 start /Users/julie/Documents/groupe_rocher/spark-administration/spark-administration-bff
> node .

[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart